# The spectrum of self adjoint bounded operator on a Hilbert space - Why not use $\sigma(T^*)=\bar{\sigma(T)}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $T$ be a bounded self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $\cal H$. Denote by $\sigma(T)$ the spectrum of $T$.
I wish to prove that the spectrum of a self-adjoint operator is contained in the real line.
I sense it is a dumb question, but is it not enough to use the fact that $\lambda\in \sigma(T)$ if and only if $\bar{\lambda}\in \sigma(T^*)$?

Since $T=T^*$, we'll have $\lambda=\bar{\lambda}$, thus $\lambda$ is real.
Note that I've encounter the several questions asked here regarding this issue (such as the ones I attached below), but none answered my question.

[Spectrum of self-adjoint operator on Hilbert space real](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925097/spectrum-of-self-adjoint-operator-on-hilbert-space-real)
[On the spectrum of a self-adjoint operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3094655/on-the-spectrum-of-a-self-adjoint-operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't deduce that $\lambda = \overline{\lambda}$ immediately. All you know is that if $\lambda \in \sigma(T)$, then there is $\mu \in \sigma(T)$ with $\lambda = \overline{\mu}$.  How do you conclude $\lambda = \overline{\lambda}$ from this?

Comment: Oh... I was right, it is a dumb question. Thanks :)

Comment: @Khal I wouldn't call it a dumb question. Glad I could help!